# Finding all WAV files of multiple directories and copying them to local computer from server

Tags: linux

I have a Linux server where the directory structure is

```
Mainfolder1/folder2/firstfile.wav
           /folder3/secondfile.wav
           /folder4/thirdfile.wav
Mainfolder2/folder1/fourthfile.wav
```

Now, what I want is to search all .wav files and copy those using `sz` command in my local windows machine.

Comment: So what have you tried so far? Why must you use `sz` specifically? The man page says it's for sending and receiving files over a dial-in serial port. Are you sure `scp` can't be used instead?

Comment: either way is fine but while using sz command I don't have to give the path details of my windows pc

Comment: So your client machine is running Windows? If so, please edit the question to specify this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
find /Mainfolder1 /Mainfolder2 -iname \*.wav -exec sz {} \;
```

will execute `sz <filename>` for each matched file, run it without -exec first to see which files it finds, so that you can check the list of file before running it for real.

I see sz can read filenames from stdin so this might be more efficient,
`find /Mainfolder1 /Mainfolder2 -iname \*.wav | sz -`

Comment: +1 but careful with that pipe, `-exec` is much safer for files with names containing spaces, backslashes and other strange characters.